# Database Serializability - how to check

Tags: sql, database, serialization, scheduler

I'm struggling to find a definition / explanation here for this question (college exam related):

"Consider the following schedules. The actions are listed in the order they are scheduled, and prefixed with the transaction name.

Find if S1 and S2 are **serializable**, **conflict serializable**, **view serializable** ?"

```
S1: T2:R(B), T2:W(B), T1:W(A), T1:R(B), T3:R(A), T1:W(B), T2:W(A)

S2: T1:R(B), T3:R(A), T3:W(A), T2:R(B), T2:W(A), T3:W(C), T1:R(A), T2:R(C)
```

I have no problem with "conflict serializable" (draw a precedence graph, check for cycles - if acyclic then is conflict serializable) or even "view serializable", as there are tonnes of references for both.

But I'm unsure as to the sequence / steps for how to check if it's "serializable" (first one) - any ideas, tools , tips or tricks or links ? I really appreciate it.

I understand that to be "serializable" it needs to have an outcome (resultant DB state) equivalent to a serial schedule, however I just can't find the steps for how to check this.